# Input field containing double quotes value

Tags: php, html

In my PHP project I have a value containing special characters like ",', etc. (" 5 " inches, '3.5' inches, etc.). But it does not appear in a text field. How can I display this?

Is it possible to display this value in a text box?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Use [htmlentities](http://php.net/htmlentities):

```
<input value="<?php echo htmlentities($value);?>">
```

Comment: What if you want to save this values not enconded in the database? You have to apply each time `html_entity_decode();` before doing the SQL INSERT ? That doens't sound good

Comment: yes123, no, you don't. This encoding will ensure the values are correct in the HTML document. The web browser will automatically send it in the correct, normal format.

Comment: better to combine with `stripcslashes()`

Comment: Shivan, there is no reason to strip any slashes here. What you want to do is encode the string for HTML view, you don't need to do any other filtering.

Comment: If you want both single and double quotes to be able to go in, use the ENT_QUOTES flag `htmlentities($value,ENT_QUOTES)` Also, I recently ran into an issue with UTF-8, so depending on your needs, you may want to pass 'UTF-8' as the encoding (third parameter).

Answer (score 12):

I suppose your "text box" is an HTML `<input>` element?

If so, you are displaying it using something like this:

```
echo '<input name="..." value="' . $yourValue . '" />';
```

If it's the case, you need to escape the HTML that's contained in your variable, with [`htmlspecialchars`](http://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars):

```
echo '<input name="..." value="' . htmlspecialchars($yourValue) . '" />';
```

Note that you might have to add a couple of parameters, especially to specify the encoding your are using.

This way, considering `$yourValue` has been initialized like this :

```
$yourValue = '5 " inches';
```

You'll get from this generated HTML:

```
<input name="..." value="5 " inches" />
```

To that one, which works much better:

```
<input name="..." value="5 &quot; inches" />
```

Comment: So what happens when you submit that input field? Will it go into a database like &quot; and then you'll have to convert it somewhere else? What if you want to submit it with the actual double quote in it.

Comment: +1 for being more descriptive, mentioning encoding and since `htmlspecialchars()` is enough.

Answer (score 8):

For UTF-8 I went for `htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")` which did the trick.

[stack source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5679795/1066234)

Answer (score 5):

When using character set UTF-8, I use the code below to get Iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn *and* double (or single) quotes right:

```
<input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo htmlentities(stripslashes(utf8_decode($title))); ?>" />
```

PS: This is useful after someone submitted the form, but when the input is not validated.

Comment: I prefer to use `stripcslashes()` to preserve change lines.

Answer (score 2):

I've found if you have double quotes in a variable in JavaScript (from Ajax/database whatever) and you want to put it in a field - if you build the whole field/form HTML content and then swap that into a div using innerHTML, the double quotes in the value will cause problems. I was doing this and I couldn't figure a way around it by escaping either.

You should build the HTML content with the field and swap it in first, and then do a document.getElementById('myfieldid').value = thevalue; instead and it works fine.

Comment: For a Javascript solution this worked and got me out of a jam. No one mentioned this thread needed to be in PHP. So I took away your -1. :) Thanks for figuring this out. Otherwise it would have taken me all night to fix a bug.

Comment: Thanks :) It was a bizarre problem and I couldn't believe that escaping didn't work. Good to know it helped, and that I'm not the only one that had this pain of a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I use this trick:

```
$s = str_replace("& amp ;", "&", (htmlentities(stripslashes($s), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')));
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to apply `htmlspecialcars()` to the query result array. I found [a useful solution from here](http://www.hawkee.com/snippet/8641/) (see the comment by sean).

```
// Create a cleaning function
function _clean(&$value) {
  $value = htmlspecialchars($value);
  //$value = htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES); // Alternative
}

// Fetch the data from DB somehow (sqlQ is a custom function)
$q = "...";
$r = $d->sqlQ($q);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

//...call the function recursively (not always necessary) to the resultset row
array_walk_recursive($row, '_clean');
```

It does quite a bit unnecessary work if you fetch only a few text columns, but at least you don't need to write the `htmlspecialchars()` function to the HTML form multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 echo '<input name="..." value="' . htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($yourValue)) . '" />';
```

or

```
<input name="..." value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($value)); ?>">
```

Good luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the best way to manage single and double quotes (and other special chars) with HTML input is mimicking it via textarea field.
So just create a textarea instead of input field and give some styles to make it look like a native input.

```
<textarea class="fake-input"> quote's and other quote"s </textarea>
<style>
.fake-input {
    height: 20px; /* based on your font-size */
    resize: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: /* your input width */
}
</style>
```