# htmlentities destroys utf-8 strings

Tags: php

I got something weird happening here and I can't understand why, on my php 5.2.5 server (Just on Linux ,Windows php servers doesn't have same problem) 
When I use a POST Form to post the content on an input containing "é" and on the other side I

```
echo(htmlentities($_POST["myinput"]))
```

it echos `&Atilde;&copy;`

But if I echo my

```
$_POST["myinput"]
```

simply it shows "é", so this mean my htmlentities doesn't use UTF-8 by default, where can I change the Charset used by htmlentities?

I tried changing it in my php.ini default_charset = "UTF-8", but it won't work either?

Comment: First port of call: The [manual](http://www.php.net/htmlentities). :)

Comment: I've read the manual, my question is how can I change de default encoding of htmlentities...it says ISO-8859-1 is used by default, the notion of "default" implies that it can be change somewhere...but even when I changed the default_charset used by php it did not work.

Comment: It's worth noting that you don't need HTML entities to display `é` in an HTML documented encoded as UTF-8.

Comment: What we want to eacape is < > with htmlspecialchar, but we notice the bug was also affecting htmlentities.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")`

This is also better at preventing xss than just `htmlentities()`

Comment: You are right, but still I am pretty sure I never used the 3rd params and I never got that problem, could this be related to a change my host did recently?

Comment: This is great! For me, MySQL had columns as 'UTF-8' (great!), but even setting the charset to UTF-8 client side didn't work as I was using `htmlentities()` which was breaking the ć character from the polish language (they were black diamonds with question marks). These extra two parameters saved me hours, thanks!

Comment: From official manual htmlentities() takes an optional third argument encoding which defines encoding used in conversion. From PHP 5.6.0, default_charset value is used as default. From PHP 5.4.0, UTF-8 is the default. PHP prior to 5.4.0, ISO-8859-1 is used as the default. Although this argument is technically optional, you are highly encouraged to specify the correct value for your code. http://fi2.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: With same parameters using htmlentities() I had the same problem, but switching to htmlspecialchars() as this answer suggested fixed the problem on my side. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In version 5.4.0 the default value for the encoding parameter was changed to UTF-8.

Source: [Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: And changed again in 5.6.0.
"From PHP 5.6.0, default_charset value is used as default."

Answer (score 3):

The only way to change `htmlentities()`'s encoding is specifying it in its third parameter.

There is no way to change the default encoding. Prior to PHP 5.4 It is always `iso-8859-1`.

This was changed in PHP 5.4 however and is now always `utf-8`

Answer (score 1):

From php [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) : htmlentities() takes an optional third argument encoding which defines encoding used in conversion. From PHP 5.6.0, default_charset value is used as default. From PHP 5.4.0, UTF-8 is the default. PHP prior to 5.4.0, ISO-8859-1 is used as the default. Although this argument is technically optional, you are highly encouraged to specify the correct value for your code.

Answer (score 0):

And if you don't want to worry about so many different charset codings or if htmlentities doesn't work for you, here the alternative:
I used mysqli DB connection (and PHPV5)  Form post for writing/inserting to MySQl DB.

```
$Notes = $_POST['Notes']; //can be text input or textarea.

$charset = mysqli_character_set_name($link);  //mysqli connection
printf ("To check your character set but not necessary %s\n",$charset);  

$Notes = str_replace('"', '&quot;', $Notes);  //double quotes for mailto: emails.  
$von = array("ä","ö","ü","ß","Ä","Ö","Ü"," ","é");  //to correct double whitepaces as well
$zu  = array("&auml;","&ouml;","&uuml;","&szlig;","&Auml;","&Ouml;","&Uuml;","&nbsp;","&#233;");  
$Notes = str_replace($von, $zu, $Notes);  
echo " Notes:".$Notes."<br>" ;  
$Notes = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $Notes); //for mysqli DB connection.
// Escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement

echo " Notes:".$Notes ;  //ready for inserting
```

Comment: in  [http://www.danshort.com/HTMLentities/index.php?w=punct](http://www.danshort.com/HTMLentities/index.php?w=punct) are more htmlentities.

Comment: When  displaying the contents: And this line in the header if funny characters appear.<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">