# PHP string functions: which ones will work with UTF-8?

Tags: php, string, multibyte-functions

In the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) string functions are listed that work on byte level. This works for SBCS strings, but not for MBCS strings. Luckily one famous encoding UTF-8 is backward compatible up to 7 bit US-ASCII.

Since PHP 5.6 the default encoding has changed to UTF-8, but it's string functions have not. The well known alternatives are [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.iconv.php), [Multibyte String](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) and [Intl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php). Also PCRE functions can be MBCS compliant when compiled in the right way.

When SBCS code of age needs to be transformed to VMBCS (UTF-8) compliance, the standard PHP byte string functions needs to be rewritten to be MBCS safe. Although the most basic functions (like `strpos()`) have an `mb_*` variant (like `mb_strpos()`) most of PHP's string functions have no `mb_` counterpart. For continued use they have to be rewritten.

In the first stage, one needs to determine which SBCS string functions will work despite their byte oriented nature. Some have been identified already on SO, what I'm looking for now is a comprehensive list of functions that will work with UTF-8, or when used with caution, for example parameters with US-ASCII only. To clarify, the question is not about the byte string functions like `chr()` or `crc32()`, it's about getting a list of functions like:

- Not safe: `count_chars()` counts bytes, ...
- Caution: `ltrim()` will work as long as parameters are US-ASCII, ...
- Safe: `str_repeat()` will work with MBCS strings, ...

Would anybody know such a list?

Comment: Have you searched [the list of PHP string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) in the documentation?

Comment: Yes, I just need a list to know which functions to rewrite.

Comment: Providing a list of stuff is a bad fit for SO, but it's enough of an issue in PHP that it's a reasonable question. Unfortunately the most viable thing is to really understand UTF-8 and what each individual string function does, from which you can conclude yourself whether what you're doing is safe or not. Yeah, not a terribly satisfying answer, I know…

Comment: @deceze I've seen many questions whether function X is multibyte safe. While those questions do fit SO I agree with the bad fit. I've considered SO Documentation, but I've read they're going to change the structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Core PHP SBCS string functions

Assuming the [default encoding of PHP is set to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351694/setting-php-default-encoding-to-utf-8), **these string functions will work**:

- [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) Output one or more strings
- [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) Convert all HTML entities to their applicable characters
- [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) Convert all applicable characters to HTML entities | better use
- [`htmlspecialchars_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php) Convert special HTML entities back to characters
- [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) Convert special characters to HTML entities
- [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) Join array elements with a string
- [`join`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.join.php) Alias of implode
- [`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) Inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string
- [`print`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php) Output a string
- [`quotemeta`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.quotemeta.php) Quote meta characters
- [`str_repeat`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php) Repeat a string
- [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) Strip HTML and PHP tags from a string
- [`stripcslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripcslashes.php) Un-quote string quoted with addcslashes
- [`stripslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) Un-quotes a quoted string

Unfortunately **all other string functions do not work** with UTF-8.
Obstacles:

- case handling or spaces does not work with UTF-8
- string lengths in parameters and return values are not in character lengths
- string processing causes data corruption
- string function is comletely ASCII oriented

In some cases functions can work as expected when parameters are US-ASCII and
lengths are byte lenghts.

Binary string function are **still useful**:

- [`bin2hex`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php) Convert binary data into hexadecimal representation
- [`chr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) Return a specific character (=byte)
- [`convert_uudecode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.convert-uudecode.php) Decode a uuencoded string
- [`convert_uuencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.convert-uuencode.php) Uuencode a string
- [`crc32`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php) Calculates the crc32 polynomial of a string
- [`crypt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) One-way string hashing
- [`hex2bin`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php) Decodes a hexadecimally encoded binary string
- [`md5_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5-file.php) Calculates the md5 hash of a given file
- [`md5`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) Calculate the md5 hash of a string
- [`ord`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) Return ASCII value of character (=byte)
- [`sha1_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1-file.php) Calculate the sha1 hash of a file
- [`sha1`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php) Calculate the sha1 hash of a string

Configuration functions **do not apply**:

- [`get_html_translation_table`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-html-translation-table.php) Returns the translation table used by htmlspecialchars and htmlentities
- [`localeconv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.localeconv.php) Get numeric formatting information
- [`nl_langinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl-langinfo.php) Query language and locale information
- [`setlocale`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) Set locale information

*[Regular expression functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44482056/php-support-for-multibyte-safe-regular-expressions) and encoding and transcoding functions are not considered.*

#### Extentions

In quite a few cases, [Multibyte String](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php)
offers an UTF-8 variant:

- [`mb_convert_case`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-case.php) Perform case folding on a string
- [`mb_parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-parse-str.php) Parse GET/POST/COOKIE data and set global variable
- [`mb_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php) Split multibyte string using regular expression
- [`mb_strcut`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strcut.php) Get part of string
- [`mb_strimwidth`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strimwidth.php) Get truncated string with specified width
- [`mb_stripos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-stripos.php) Finds position of first occurrence of a string within another, case insensitive
- [`mb_stristr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-stristr.php) Finds first occurrence of a string within another, case insensitive
- [`mb_strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) Get string length
- [`mb_strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strpos.php) Find position of first occurrence of string in a string
- [`mb_strrchr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strrchr.php) Finds the last occurrence of a character in a string within another
- [`mb_strrichr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strrichr.php) Finds the last occurrence of a character in a string within another, case insensitive
- [`mb_strripos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strripos.php) Finds position of last occurrence of a string within another, case insensitive
- [`mb_strrpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strrpos.php) Find position of last occurrence of a string in a string
- [`mb_strstr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strstr.php) Finds first occurrence of a string within another
- [`mb_strtolower`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php) Make a string lowercase
- [`mb_strtoupper`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtoupper.php) Make a string uppercase
- [`mb_strwidth`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strwidth.php) Return width of string
- [`mb_substr_count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr-count.php) Count the number of substring occurrences
- [`mb_substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) Get part of string

And **[iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.iconv.php)** provides a bare minimum of string functions:

- [`iconv_strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-strlen.php) Returns the character count of string
- [`iconv_strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-strpos.php) Finds position of first occurrence of a needle within a haystack
- [`iconv_strrpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-strrpos.php) Finds the last occurrence of a needle within a haystack
- [`iconv_substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-substr.php) Cut out part of a string

Lastly **[Intl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php)** has a lot of extra and powerful Unicode features (but no regular expressions) as part of [i18n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization). Some features overlap with other string functions. With respect to string functions these are:

- [IntlBreakIterators](http://php.net/manual/en/class.intlbreakiterator.php)
- [Grapheme Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.intl.grapheme.php)

Answer (score 1):

The [PHP standard string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) are not able to handle multi-byte strings correctly. They handle their arguments as single-byte character strings, no matter what kind of strings you pass to them. They don't operate on characters but on bytes.

PHP doesn't keep the encoding of each string. It handles all of them the same way.

The [PHP multi-byte string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) provided by the [`mbstring` PHP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) can handle multiple character encodings, convert between encodings and auto-detect the encoding of a given string. They operate on characters and are able to handle both fixed-length encodings (UTF-16, f.e.) and variable-length encodings (UTF-8).

Comment: +1 for mostly true, PHP operates on byte level yes, which means that those functions will mess up your MBCS. But UTF-8 is US-ASCII compliant, some functions will work despite their 8-bit byte design.

Comment: All PHP string functions work well with UTF-8 encoded strings as long as the strings use only 7-bit ASCII characters (because the encoding of the first 128 characters is identical in ASCII and UTF-8).

Comment: There are many standard string functions which work just fine on UTF-8 strings, e.g. `str_replace`. Due to the nature of what they're doing it doesn't matter whether they operate on a byte or character basis. Others on the other hand will fail, e.g. `trim` with a custom non-ASCII character mask (but with an ASCII-only mask it works just fine as well).

Comment: @axiac Not true, check [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) which [does work with UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679715/htmlentities-destroys-utf-8-strings#answer-5679795).