# Echoing Value With Quotation Marks Into HTML Input Tag

Tags: php, html

I am trying to echo a value from an sql server into an html input tag value that contains quotation marks ( " ) to symbolize inches with this code:

```
<input type="text" name="ProductMeasurement" value="<?php echo $row->materialdescriptionvalue; ?>">
```

(The value it is trying to echo is: AL Checker 1/8" x 48" x 120") But because of the numerous quotation marks in the echo it ends up echoing "AL Checker 1/8" stopping at the first quotation mark. it has to be an input tag and not a text tag because it has to be user-editable and its value has to be able to be retrieved from php.

How can I have quotation marks in the value section of the input tag?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Input field containing double quotes value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004298/input-field-containing-double-quotes-value) for existing answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="ProductMeasurement" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row->materialdescriptionvalue, ENT_QUOTES); ?>">
```

In the above code, htmlspecialchars($row->materialdescriptionvalue, ENT_QUOTES) will convert all instances of double and single quotes to their HTML entities (" for double quotes, ' for single quotes), thus preventing them from interfering with your HTML markup.

Comment: Did you generate this answer using a tool like ChatGPT?

Comment: OP doesn't want to replace the double quotes but to echo them